# Discord.py giving permission to text channel by user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I figured out how to give text channel permissions by role in Discord.py, I was wondering how to do the same but by user ID instead

Comment: [You can use `permissions_for` for user permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel)

Answer (score 0):

The `channel.set_permissions` function also accepts a member object as the first argument, not just a role.
You can do something like this:

```
await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=False, reason="Muted")
```